# Porting Ruby USB code to latest versions of Linux?

Tags: usb, libraries, ruby, rubygems

I have some Ruby code that I've been using on Linux. It looks like this:

```
require 'usb'
dev = nil # will be a USB::Device
USB.devices.each { |x|
  if x.idProduct==1 && x.idVendor==0x08f7 then dev=x end   
  ...
```

I used to be able to get this to work by installing the following libraries on Mint or Ubuntu:

```
libusb-1.0-0 libusb-ruby
```

In the latest versions of mint and Ubuntu `libusb-ruby` no longer exists. It seems like there has been a change in naming conventions of some packages from, e.g., `libjson-ruby` to `ruby-json`. However, there doesn't seem to be a `ruby-usb` library.

Googling on search terms like ruby and USB turns up a lot of confusing stuff. There seem to be a bunch of libraries out there, and I'm having a hard time figuring out whether there is any particular library that still exists as an Ubuntu package and has the same API:

- https://github.com/larskanis/libusb
- https://github.com/akr/ruby-usb
- https://www.thekua.com/atwork/2012/05/usb-programming-with-ruby/

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to get this working again? If there is no Ubuntu package anymore for this, do I need to install it as a Ruby Gem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gem that used to be packaged as `libusb-ruby` or similar in distributions is most likely [ruby-usb](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-usb).

At least your code worked fine when I used that gem.

I would suggest that you add a Gemfile to your project and use RubyGems to manage those gems, as some of the less popular gems are often likely to drop out of distributions when no maintainer for the package can be found.

The following Gemfile did the trick:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'ruby-usb'
```

The disadvantage is that you'll need a compiler on that machine, and also the libusb development packages (on Debian, that's `libusb-dev`).

Comment: I confirmed that that's the gem `ruby-usb`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The following is what I had to do: `sudo apt-get install libusb-dev ruby1.9.1-dev`
  `sudo gem sources -a  http://rubygems.org`
  `sudo gem install ruby-usb` I didn't have to modify the ruby source code.